# Сортировка map по значению java

Tags: java

Есть `map<Integer,Integer>`, как ее отсортировать по значению?

Comment: Вытащите коллекцию entries и отсортируйте.

Comment: карта это не то место где надо сортировать "по значению". в самом лучше случае можно вытащить map.values(), но внутри самой карты НИКАК. потому что позиция значений зависит от ключа(хеша ключа).

Comment: Насколько помню `Java`, если для реализации `Map`  использовать [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html), то  перебор членов коллекции будет происходить (по умолчанию) в порядке возрастания ключей.

Таким образом, специально сортировать не потребуется.

Comment: @avp: Насколько я понимаю, ТС хочет сортировку не по ключам, а по значениям.

Comment: @ttt: Как вы представляете себе map, «отсортированный по значениям»? Какие операции будут выполняться по-другому?

Comment: @VladD, точно. Невнимательно я прочел вопрос...

--

@ttt, а если абстрагироваться от программной реализации, *то что, на самом деле, Вы хотите сделать?* (лучше просто русскими словами).

Answer (score 18):

**java 8**

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        map.put(1, 10);
        map.put(2, 30);
        map.put(3, 50);
        map.put(4, 40);
        map.put(5, 100);
        map.put(6, 60);
        map.put(7, 110);
        map.put(8, 50);
        map.put(9, 90);
        map.put(10, 70);
        map.put(11, 80);

        map.entrySet().stream()
        .sorted(Map.Entry.<Integer, Integer>comparingByValue().reversed()) 
        .forEach(System.out::println); // или любой другой конечный метод
  }
}
```

**Вывод:**

```
7=110
5=100
9=90
11=80
10=70
6=60
3=50
8=50
4=40
2=30
1=10
```

Comment: Если помог) апните ответ)

Answer (score 10):

```
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    List list = new ArrayList(map.entrySet());
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> a, Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> b) {
            return a.getValue() - b.getValue();
        }
    });
Исправил
```

Comment: Вы потеряли информацию о ключах

Answer (score 8):

Сходу написать такой сортировщик не так просто. По крайней мере, я для себя выбрал в этом случае такую стратегию: *раз написал, много раз используй*. Поэтому такой сортировщик я написал через `Generics` т.к. в `map` может иметь и другие типы в качестве ключа и значения.

Ниже я поделюсь двумя версиями сортировочного метода. Для `Java version = 7` и для `Java version = 8`.

Итак, если у Вас 7-я версия Java:

```
public static <K, V extends Comparable<? super V>> Map<K, V> 
    sortByValue(Map<K, V> map )
{
    List<Map.Entry<K, V>> list =
        new LinkedList<>(map.entrySet());
    Collections.sort( list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<K, V>>()
    {
        @Override
        public int compare(Map.Entry<K, V> o1, Map.Entry<K, V> o2)
        {
            return (o1.getValue()).compareTo( o2.getValue() );
        }
    } );

    Map<K, V> result = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (Map.Entry<K, V> entry : list)
    {
        result.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
    return result;
}
```

Т.е., сначала, как писал @Nofate, вытаскиваем список entries (это у нас переменная `list`), затем сортируем эти entries по значениям и заливаем в новую мапу (это у нас `result`). Для результирующей мапы я использовал `LinkedHashMap` чтобы при добавлении элементы не пересортировывались.

А вот версия с использованием `Stream`'ов из Java 8:

```
public static <K, V extends Comparable<? super V>> Map<K, V> 
    sortByValue( Map<K, V> map )
{
      Map<K,V> result = new LinkedHashMap<>();
     Stream <Entry<K,V>> st = map.entrySet().stream();

     st.sorted(Comparator.comparing(e -> e.getValue()))
          .forEach(e ->result.put(e.getKey(),e.getValue()));

     return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Делаем два ArrayList-а с ключом и значением. Парсим HashMap, сразу сортируя по значению.

```
    ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Float> floats = new ArrayList<>();

    for (HashMap.Entry<String, Float> e : map.entrySet()) {
        float value = e.getValue();
        boolean isAdded = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < floats.size(); i++) {
            if (value > floats.get(i)) {
                floats.add(i, value);
                strings.add(i, e.getKey());
                isAdded = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!isAdded) {
            floats.add(value);
            strings.add(e.getKey());
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < strings.size(); i++) {
        Log.d(TAG, "sort: " + strings.get(i) + "=" + floats.get(i));
    }
```

На выходе отсортированные ArrayList-ы.

Comment: эм... но ведь задача отсортировать мапу, а вы переводите все в листы

Comment: Поэтому наличествует второй цикл, в котором можно объединить ключи-значения в нужном виде.

Comment: проблема в том, что если в этом цикле использовать HashMap то все сортировка пропадет. Если использовать TreeMap то сортировка будет дефолтная по ключу, ваша так же пропадет. Последний вариант это LinkedHashMap

Answer (score 0):

```
listWorkers.entrySet().stream().sorted(Map.Entry.<String, Integer>comparingByValue().reversed()) 
        .forEach(System.out::println);

//listWorkers - название вашего листа
//и будьте  внимательны с Map.Entry.<String, Integer>(тут должен быть ваш тип данных)
```

Comment: Ответ по сути не отличается от [предыдущего](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/664812/386633) варианта 2017 года.

Answer (score -1):

```
TreeMap< String ,Integer> map= new TreeMap< String,Integer>();  
SortedMap<Integer, String> sortMapa = new TreeMap<Integer, String>(new IntegerComparator<Integer>());   
 Iterator<?> it = map.entrySet().iterator();     

 while(it.hasNext())
 {   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Entry< String ,Integer> En = (Entry<String, Integer>) it.next();    
    sortMapa.put( En.getValue(), En.getKey());

 }  

 Iterator<?> sortit = sortMapa.entrySet().iterator();    
 while(sortit.hasNext())
 {   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Entry< Integer,String > sEn = (Entry<Integer,String>) sortit.next();    
    System.out.println(sEn.getValue()+"-->"+sEn.getKey());       

 }
```

Comment: Ошибка просто так из мапы в мапу перелить нельзя! Я ставлю значение в sortMapa  а качестве ключа Но ключи то уникальны,а значения нет. Так что так писать нельзя, потеря данных....