# Сортировка Map по значению с сохранением результата в HashMap

Tags: java, словари, java-hashmap

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    HashMap<Integer, Double> map = new HashMap<Integer, Double>();
    map.put(1, 10.0);
    map.put(2, 30.0);
    map.put(3, 50.0);
    map.put(4, 40.0);
    map.put(5, 100.0);
    map.put(6, 60.0);
    map.put(7, 110.0);
    map.put(8, 50.0);
    map.put(9, 90.0);
    map.put(10, 70.0);
    map.put(11, 80.0);

    map.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(Map.Entry.<Integer, Double>comparingByValue().reversed()) 
    .forEach(System.out::println); // или любой другой конечный метод
  }
 }
```

Нашел пример [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/330039/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-map-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E-java), сортировка Map по значению и он отлично работает, вот только ума не приложу, как сохранить результат в HashMap минуя вывод в консоль?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HashMap` не сохраняет порядок ключей, используйте `LinkedHashMap`

Пример:

```
...

Map<Integer, Double> newMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
map.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .sorted(Map.Entry.<Integer, Double>comparingByValue().reversed())
        .forEach(entry -> newMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));

System.out.println(newMap);
```

Результат:

```
{7=110.0, 5=100.0, 9=90.0, 11=80.0, 10=70.0, 6=60.0, 3=50.0, 8=50.0, 4=40.0, 2=30.0, 1=10.0}
```

Answer (score 1):

"Правильнее" будет не добавлять в существующую мапу (которая должна быть `LinkedHashMap`), а использовать коллектор `toMap` с указанием `Supplier<Map>` (тогда также придется указать функцию слияния):

```java
Map<Integer, Double> sortedByValue = map.entrySet()
    .parallelStream()
    .sorted(Map.Entry.<Integer, Double>comparingByValue().reversed())
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Map.Entry::getKey,
        Map.Entry::getValue,
        (a, b) -> a,
        LinkedHashMap::new
    ));
```

Этот вариант будет работать в случае применения параллельного стрима, тогда как `forEach` придётся заменить на `forEachOrdered`.